# Are there any sets where it is an open question whether the set is open (or closed)?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, open-problem

Proving whether a set is open or closed in a topological space can be difficult at times, so I'm curious if there are any sets where it is an open question whether they are open or closed.

Obviously, you can construct trivial questions like $S=\mathbb{R}$ if some open question is true, but of course that is not what I am looking for.

Comment: You seem to imply that most sets are open or closed, but almost all sets are neither.  There are $2^{\mathfrak c}$ subsets of the reals, but only $\mathfrak c$ open subsets and the same number of closed subsets of the reals.

Comment: @RossMillikan I see.

Comment: I'm curious as to why all the answers seem to think they're so funny by deliberately missing the point. Obviously OP is interested in open (ha!) questions in topology or algebraic geometry that are naturally stated as a question about the openness of sets, not trivial restatements of open questions in other fields of mathematics. Clearly if someone were to ask about series that we don't know converge or not,  "The series of the sequence that is all ones when the Riemann hypothesis is true, and all zeroes otherwise" would not be an interesting answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nobody knows if the set of all reciprocals of Mersenne primes is closed. Or take the set of all reciprocals of odd perfect numbers; it is conjectured that it's open, there is a weaker conjecture that it's closed, but nobody knows.

Comment: Wow really? Is there a reason why those are open questions, particular with the perfect numbers?

Comment: It is not known whether there are infinitely many [Mersenne primes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) (which are related to even perfect numbers), and it is not known whether there are any [odd perfect numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/OddPerfectNumber.html) at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to make a contrived one.  Take any open yes-or-no question, let your set be
$(0, 1)$ if the answer is no and $[0,1]$ if the answer is yes (as subsets of $\mathbb R$).

Comment: True, but this is not exactly what I am asking for.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler:  but it shows you have to define what you are asking for.  What types of definition are allowed?

Comment: @RossMillikan The usual definition of openness is sufficient, but I am particularly looking for non-contrived examples.

Comment: @SpencerKraisler:  I was referring to the definition of the set.  You didn't like this one.  What ways of defining the set that might be open or closed are acceptable?  I assume you are using open and closed based on the usual topology of the reals, so that is not in question.

Comment: Well, we can define $A = \mathbb R - K$ where $K = \{n\in \mathbb N|$ then decimal representation $n$ does not occur in the decimal expansion of $\pi\}$.  If $K$ is empty then $A=\mathbb R$ is closed.  If $K$ is not empty then $A$ is $\mathbb R$ with isolated points removed and is not closed.

Answer (score 0):

Let $\gamma$ be the Euler-Mascheroni constant. The set $S=\{x \in \mathbb{Q}|x \le \gamma\}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $\gamma$ is irrational, which is an unsolved problem. So the openness of $S$ is open.